# how to view 3D viewport material preview with background?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, 3d-view, eevee-render-engine

I'm in the shading layout, looking at the 3D viewport. I switch to preview material mode, and turn off Lighting->Scene World. The background shows only a lightly gradiented multi tone color. Is there a key to change this to display the hdri background?

Comment: Hello :). This question keeps popping up as unanswered. Please mark one of the answers as accepted **✓**, or post your own solution. Just to keep the site nice and tidy. Thanks :).

Answer (score 2):

There's a simple workaround.
Put a plane with *Glass BSDF* material in the background and the HDRi will show.

*No need to adjust or enable anything. It just works.*

[image]

Comment: That is a good suggestion !